# refresh a materialized view after update of tables

Tags: postgresql, view, trigger

I am currently stuck in postgres at creating an updateable `MATERIALIZED VIEW`.

The `MATERIALIZED VIEW` consists basically from 2 (foreign) tables.

This is an example for the tables:

```
id | data
---+------
 1 | foo

id | data
---+------
 1 | bar
```

A `UNION` is used to generate the `VIEW` and also to create unique IDs (but thats a different story):

```
id | data
---+------
 1 | foo
 2 | bar
```

I want the materialized VIEW to be updateable, meaning, I want to redirect `UPDATE`s on the data to the corresponding tables.

So I have a 'regular' `VIEW` on my `MATERIALIZED VIEW` with a `SELECT *` and Triggers/Rules (both worked for my case) which handle `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateOrigTable() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
  DECLARE
    myID IN;
  BEGIN
    IF myID > (SELECT MAX(table1.id) FROM table1) THEN
      myID := myID - (SELECT MAX(table1.id) FROM table1);
      UPDATE table2 SET dummy_data = NEW.country WHERE table2.id = myID;
    ELSE
      UPDATE table1 SET dummy_data = NEW.country WHERE users1.id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql volatile;

CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger  
  INSTEAD OF UPDATE  
  ON myView
  FOR EACH ROW  
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE updateOrigTable();
```

I also want to create a `TRIGGER`, that is triggered on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, which performs a `REFRESH`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION matViewRefresh()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY matView;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER matViewRefresh 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON table1 FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE matViewRefresh();
  
CREATE TRIGGER matViewRefresh 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON table2 FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE matViewRefresh();
```

However, when I try to update `myView`, it gives me

> ERROR: REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW with Relation »matView« not possible because it is used by active queries in this session (translated from German)

I do not understand why this blocks. The refresh happens **after** the update, so the database object from `matView` should already be unblocked.

Is there a way to create a hardcopy of the database object in my update procedure?

Any other hints?

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you create the trigger as a deferrable initially deferred constraint trigger. So instead of

```
CREATE TRIGGER matViewRefresh 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON table1 FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE matViewRefresh();
```

do

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER matViewRefresh
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
    ON table1
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE matViewRefresh();
```

Comment: can you elaborate or make a fiddle with it

Comment: I just updated my answer.